# RNTMap was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am following along the official documentation, copy and pasting the code provided there:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/native-components-ios

But I am still running into this error [image: screenshot]

does anyone know what the docs are missing to get this working?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I can't find anything in the docs about why this occurs. I've trawled through plenty of sample code as well, and nothing I do seems to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

RNTMapManager.m must be created within the XCode project, the docs do not specify that. Open the XCode project and click File -> New -> File and create a new Cocoa Touch Class called "RNTMapManager". Then place the objective-c code within RNTMapManager.m. Rebuild the application and it should work!

Comment: Thanks @JPritchard9518, after spending hours on this using VS Code, using XCode to add the files worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is happens because native module not compiled yet, simply execute **`react-native run-ios`** in terminal while in project directory.

**Note:** For latest node version use: `npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

1. To be able to use native components make sure your project was ejected (expo eject)
2. Once ejected open for example iOS project with XCode and create/add file from Xcode. This way it will update all the dependencies.
3. Rebuild the project

Comment: The **with Xcode** on step 2 did the trick for me, I tried adding the files in VS Code and running `pod install` like other solutions I saw without any luck.